# Docker: Multiple services within a single container, how to access localhost?

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask, dockerfile, supervisord

I have set up a Flask backend and  React frontend in a single container with -buster (Debian) image base and run both using Supervisord (I know it is not good practice, but it is required for my usecase). How can my React frontend component access the Flask backend endpoints? Is there a way for me to check the ports that are 'active' in the Debian OS?

My frontend is using port 3000, with the port exposed to my machine during Docker run command:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 test_app
```

My backend is using port 5000, and I do not want to expose a port to my machine, hence I did not expose it using `-p 5000:5000`

How can I get my react frontend to access the Flask backend endpoints within the Docker container? Might it be a supervisord configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you have a webserver running at 3000 port and another backend server running in same contaner and you want to access backend from webserver, then you can use `localhost` interface.

---

If you want to connect to backend from your react app which completely client side running the user's browser, then you can't access the backend at `localhost`. You will need to publish the backend port and connect via the port.

---

What you can instead do is have reverse-proxy gateway like nginx serving both your frontend and backend api. 
https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html

Comment: Hi! I have tried using '"http://localhost:5000"' but it is not working, shld i remove the 'http' portion?

Comment: Where is the call to "localhost:5000" being made from? Is the react app completely client side? If so, accessing "localhost:5000" won't work. You need to publish the server port and access it via the server port.

Comment: Hi! Yes the react is being served on frontend, so besides exposing port 5000 there is no way for my react app to have access to my backend?

Comment: You need to somehow expose your backend so that your client side react app can connect. You can either expose port 5000 of your backend if it is just development setup. For production setups, the standard way is to use a gateway through which you proxy the backend. Gateway can serve traffic at port 80(http) or 443(https) and act as reverse-proxy for your backend at 5000 port. I've updated the answer, please check.

Comment: I realised that I have to use a gateway service like nginx to handle this, thanks for the help! Currently figuring out how to configure it